# Combining multiple objects to create JSON object in Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to construct my own JSON object from multiple online image/photography sources. The below code should explain what I am trying to accomplish:

```
var searchUnsplash = require('./apis/unsplash');
var searchFlickr = require('./apis/flickr');

function combineObjs(callback) {

    var obj = {} 
    var key = 'item';
    obj[key] = []; 

    searchFlickr.searchFlickr(searchTerm, searchCount, searchPage,
        function (callback) { // each API call is in a separate file with these functions exported 

            obj[key].push(flickrObj); // this does not work 
            // console.log(flickrObj) // this works 
        });
    searchUnsplash.searchUnsplash(searchTerm, searchCount, searchPage, 
        function (callback) {

            obj[key].push(unsplashObj);
            // console.log(unsplashObj)
        });

    console.log(obj)
}

combineObjs();
```

The goal is to end up with a JSON object like below:

```
["item": {
    "id": 1,
    "title": 2,
    "content": 3,
    "source": "flickr"
}, 
"item": {
    "id": 1,
    "title": 2,
    "content": 3,
    "source": "unsplash"
}]
```

etc, which I can use to power my front end.

I am a beginner to javascript and I am just working off what I have learned in tutorials and articles, so I might be using the wrong approach entirely for what I am aiming to achieve. Happy to take any pointers

search function:

```
function searchUnsplash(term, count, page, callback) {
    request(`https://api.unsplash.com/search/photos/?per_page=${count}&page=${page}&query="${term}"&client_id=KEY&`, 

    function searchResult(error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        var info = JSON.parse(body)

        for ( var i = 0; i < info.results.length; i++) {

            obj = {
                id: `us-${info.results[i].id}`, 

            }
            callback(obj);

        }

    }

    })
}

module.exports.searchUnsplash = searchUnsplash;
```

Comment: Just curious why the `item = {...}` in the JSON array? Why not just have the object literals?

Comment: Your end result isn't even valid JSON, so I suggest you define what you want a little better.

Comment: Yeah sorry, I mistyped that. Long day

Comment: What happens here: `obj[key].push(flickrObj); // this does not work`?

Comment: Also, the `combineObjs` function seems to be mixing synchronous and asynchronous code and expecting the synchronous code to log something (`console.log(obj)`) but when that executes the `obj` is most likely still empty because the asynchronous code hasn't returned anything yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your intended result is not correct. You can't name `"item"` the individual array entries. A corrected and working example would be this one.

```
[ {
    "id": 1,
    "title": 2,
    "content": 3,
    "source": "flickr"
}, 
{
    "id": 1,
    "title": 2,
    "content": 3,
    "source": "unsplash"
}]
```

Second, you mistake JSON for your data structure. JSON is just the text notation. So, let's see first how to build a suitable data array.

```
let results = [];
results.push( { id:1, title:2, content:3, source:"flickr" });
results.push( { id:2, title:4, content:6, source:"unsplash" });
```

And then with `JSON.stringify(results)` will code your `results` into JSON.

Finally, you mix up the aynchronous calls in your code with synchronous invocations. You need to save the results on the callback of the individual functions, that is when you really obtain the responses asynchronously. Also, you need to count the pending results and invoke the final callback when all done.

So, putting all the pieces together, in a contrived fake example, we just invoke twice the search functions and so we callback when two results are combined.

```
function combineObjs(callback) {  
   let results = [];   
   function partialResult(obj) { 
     results.push(obj); 
     if (results.length=2) callback(results);
   }; 
   searchFlickr(searchTerm, searchCount, searchPage, partialResult);
   searchUnsplash(searchTerm, searchCount, searchPage,partialResult);    
}

combineObjs( function(results) { console.log(JSON.stringify(results)) });
```

Comment: Hey PA, thanks for the detailed answer.

I've implemented and its working although the output is iterating over and over, the last array is the one i want. I am posting my search function above, thanks in advance if you can figure out why this is happening `[ { id: 'us-fRPxHaHwWwk' } ]
[ { id: 'us-fRPxHaHwWwk' }, { id: 'us-JXy99waA3Fo' } ]
[ { id: 'us-fRPxHaHwWwk' },
  { id: 'us-JXy99waA3Fo' },
  { id: 'flkr-13545844805' } ]
[ { id: 'us-fRPxHaHwWwk' },
  { id: 'us-JXy99waA3Fo' },
  { id: 'flkr-13545844805' },
  { id: 'flkr-3474831728' } ]`

Answer (score 0):

This is excessive but it would work. It can be used over and over and over again. :D

Run the snippet to see a result

```js
class JSONBuilder
{
  constructor(contents=null)
  {
    if(!contents)
    {
      //Private objecy hash that isn't publicly accessible
      var objectHash = {};
      
      //Get stashed item
      this.GetItem = function(key)
      {
        if(!key) throw new Error("Null or Underfined Key Passed.");

        let value = objectHash[key];
        if(!value) throw new Error(`Key : ${key} Not Found in JSON objectHash`);
        return value;
      }
      
      //Set an item in the objecy hash
      this.SetItem = function(key, value)
      {
        if(!key) throw new Error("Null or Underfined Key Passed.");
        if(!value) throw new Error("Null or Underfined Key Not Found.");

        objectHash[key] = value;
      }
      
      //Remove item from the hash
      this.DeleteItem = function(key)
      {
        if(!key) throw new Error("Null or Underfined Key Passed.");
        if(!objectHash[key]) throw new Error(`Key : ${key} Not Found in JSON objectHash`);

        objectHash.DeleteItem(key);
      }
      
      //Turn items into a JSON object
      this.Build = function()
      {
        return JSON.stringify(objectHash);
      }
    }
    else
    {
      //If a string is passed as a paremeter, reconstruct from that
      try
      {
        objectHash = JSON.parse(contents);
      }
      catch(Err)
      {
        console.log("Parsing of JSON Content Failed.");
        throw Err;
      }
    }
  }
}

class Item
{
  constructor(id, source, content, title)
  {
    this.Id = id;
    this.Source = source;
    this.Content = content;
    this.Title = title;
  }
}
let builder = new JSONBuilder();
let itemContainer = [];
itemContainer.push(new Item(1, 'flicker', 'stuff', 'item1'));
itemContainer.push(new Item(2, 'flicker', 'morestuff', 'item2'));

builder.SetItem('items', itemContainer);
console.log(builder.Build());
```